# Tableview creating multiple times inside cellforrowatindexpath delegate method

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have two tableviews in my screen. 1 is maintableview, 2 is inside 1st tableviewcell I am displaying this 2nd tableview. So, I am able to differentiating while displaying date for each tableview.

But, Issue is, once I pressed on 2nd tableview cell data, I am reloading particular cell of 1st tableview cell, inside that cell I am created 2nd tableview, so, Whenever I pressed on 2nd tableview cell, 2nd tableview is repeatedly creating and adding to 1st tableviewcell.

So, code is follows inside cellforrowatindexpath delegate method

//1st tableview delegate method and reloading this indexpath multiple times by whenever clicking 2nd tableview cells data

```
else if indexPath.row == 1 {
//some action doing code

//later 2nd tableview creation
            //for no of event days like day1, day2 etc
                noOfEventDaysTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x:(cell?.secondCircleGraph.frame.maxX)! + 5,y:10,width:60,height:50), style: .plain)
                cell?.contentView.addSubview(noOfEventDaysTableView)
                noOfEventDaysTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
                noOfEventDaysTableView.delegate = self
                noOfEventDaysTableView.dataSource = self
                noOfEventDaysTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                noOfEventDaysTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
                noOfEventDaysTableView.rowHeight = 20.0

}
```

While scrolling 2nd tableview data, its coming like creating again cells.
PFA.

[image]

How to avoid once created 2nd tableview, second restrict to create again?

I can avoid by doing following

```
         noOfEventDaysTableView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Is there any better solution for this?
Any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding tableview as a "addSubview(noOfEventDaysTableView)" in "cellForRowAt indexPath" . Then please add them in tableview cell methods awakeFromNib().

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    noOfEventDaysTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x:(cell?.secondCircleGraph.frame.maxX)! + 5,y:10,width:60,height:50), style: .plain)
    cell?.contentView.addSubview(noOfEventDaysTableView)
    // Initialization code
}
```

And for compare the table view set the tag value for tableView

```
tableView.tag = 999
```

Comment: How can we achieve this?

Comment: awakeFromNib is calling only once when cell was created but "cellForRowAt "  is calling when cell is reload thats why you getting the problem.

Comment: But, I need to access the cell, then only it will work, right?, and before 1st tableview cell create, I think this logic won'r work, right?

Comment: Means you need to access the cell in same viewController Where your first tableView is present . Then you set your delegate and dataSource in "CellForRowAt" BY cell.tablView.delagte = self

Comment: But, awakeFromNib this method calls before tableview cell delegate methods calls, how can we handle?

Comment: I think we don't need to handle it, if you want to use this cell other place also, that time you need to handle them, Otherwise not .

Comment: Other place? what does it mean?

Comment: means if you use TableView1 cell as a common cell for other screen tableviews that time you you face problem otherwise not. And you chat with me on my hangout aman19ish@gmail.com

Comment: Ok, will ping there.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because of **dequeuing** so,Enumerate the **contentView** of the main tableView cell before adding to check for existence of any **UITableView** subView if not exists add it . . .

Comment: Its not helped, first time it will add, while reloading cell, it will check and shows existed, but, its not showing after reloading. So, this use case fails.